# VScode remote containers - how to view the dockerised service console output?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-remote

This is a follow on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57118268/how-to-view-docker-logs-from-vscode-remote-container) question (none of the current answers seem hit the nail on the head).

VScode's default behaviour for starting a remote vscode session (using VScode Remote-Containers) seems to be:

1. Run the project's docker-compose file

   - If the user selects *show log* (a UI popup) during build, open a VScode terminal session called `Dev Containers` reflecting Docker's build logging, supplemented with VSCode Remote-Containers logging. This output ends after build complete.
   - If the user didn't select *show log*, and later opens a VScode terminal after build complete, just start a new bash session within the container. No other VScode terminal sessions exist.
2. Launch a VScode session from inside the now-running container

From the user's perspective, the container is running, but the output that is happening inside the container seems inaccessible (even if the docker-compose `command` did not use daemon mode).

### So, how can the user now view the console output that is happening inside the container?

If I am reading correctly, VScode Remote-Containers documentation seems to suggest overriding the default behaviour, ie:

- supress your docker-compose `command` that would otherwise have started the service, and instead apply some dummy command to persist the container upon creation, then
- manually start the service (using debug mode, or via VScode terminal) from inside the remote session. This reveals the output, but within an accessible VSCode terminal session.

### Is there no way to:

A) Start the services via system terminal (e.g. `docker-compose up`), and then start a VSCode remote session in this already running container*, or

B) Accessing the service's output without having to override as above (the override seems hacky)

*This would be ideal. The Remote-Containers "Attach to Running Container..." command sounds close to this. But it seems to instantiate itself in a directory I don't recognise, and doesn't seem to be the container.

Comment: You can follow a container logs with this command: ```docker logs -f <container_name_or_id>```

Answer (score 1):

Option A seems to be achievable by

1. Starting the service in terminal (`docker-compose up`)
2. In vscode, using the remote-containers "remote explorer" UI (**not** the cmd+P "Attach to container" commands) to select the running container's working directory. Right click > "Open in container". This doesn't actually open a *new* container, it "Opens the directory, *from within the container*".

OR ( thanks @cybercoder )

1. Letting vscode start the services
2. In a separate terminal: `docker logs -f container_name` OR `docker-compose logs -f`

Comment: Instead of `docker logs -f container_name` the "remote explorer" UI can be used - just right-click the container and select 'Show Container Log'